# I have a large table with 324 columns, I want to get the list of columns which don't have any values at all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want list of columns and its table name in a database with columns having all null values.

This table is too large some columns having only null values.

I want a stored procedure which list out columns in a table which do not have any data at all (That is NULL).

So that I can trim number of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ngkbm_template_data_sets_
(
    seq_no uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    practice_id char(4) NULL,
    created_by int NOT NULL,
    create_timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
    modified_by int NOT NULL,
    modify_timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
    create_timestamp_tz smallint NULL,
    modify_timestamp_tz smallint NULL,
    row_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    chk_combo_med varchar(1) NULL,
    chk_inactive_ind varchar(1) NULL,
    chk_label_values int NULL,
    kbm_ind varchar(1) NULL,
    opt_sp int NULL,
    txt_cursor_hold varchar(1) NULL,
    txt_data_set varchar(50) NULL,
    txt_description_1 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_10 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_11 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_12 varchar(100) NULL,
    txt_description_13 varchar(100) NULL,
    txt_description_14 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_15 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_16 varchar(75) NULL,
    txt_description_17 varchar(75) NULL
)
```

I'm just showing few columns so that you can read. Orginal table has 324 columns, and millions rows of data. Perfomance is not a pressing issue for this code. I need this only for an internal purpose.

This is mysql solution, I need a SQL Server solution

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation

SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
          , 'IF('
          ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
          ,   'NULL,'
          ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
          , ') AS `column` '
          , 'FROM `', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
          SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Instead of having `txt_description_1` .... `txt_description_324` you should create a relation table `PracticeDescriptions` with at least two columns: the foreign-key `practice_id` to the main table and a column `Description`. Then it was simple: `SELECT p.* FROM dbo.ngkbm_template_data_sets_ p WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PracticeDescriptions pd WHERE p.practice_id = pd.practice_id AND pd.Description IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Now have fun with a sql query like `SELECT p.* FROM PracticeDescriptions p WHERE txt_description_1 IS NULL AND txt_description_2 IS NULL... AND .... AND .... txt_description_324 IS NULL`

Comment: The column names are different, These are first 20. from here column names are different.

The DB is not designed by me, its and 8 year old design.

I'm doing the improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick stored procedure that will do a `NULL` check on all columns in a provided table.

```
Create Procedure spGetColumnsWithAllNullValues
( 
    @Database   Varchar (100),
    @Schema     Varchar (100),
    @Table      Varchar (100)
)
As Begin

    Declare @Column Varchar (100)

    Declare @Columns Table
    (
        ColumnName Varchar (100)
    )

    Declare @Results Table
    (
        ColumnName Varchar (100)
    )

    Declare @Temp Table
    (
        Result Bit
    )

    Insert  @Columns
    Select  COLUMN_NAME
    From    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    Where   IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
    And     TABLE_CATALOG = @Database
    And     TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
    And     TABLE_NAME = @Table

    Declare cur Cursor For
    Select  ColumnName
    From    @Columns

    Open cur

    While (1 = 1)
    Begin
        Fetch Next From cur Into @Column

        If (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) Break

        Declare @sql NVarchar(Max) = N'Select Case When Exists (Select * From ' 
                                    + QuoteName(@Database) + '.' 
                                    + QuoteName(@Schema) + '.' 
                                    + QuoteName(@Table) 
                                    + ' Where ' + QuoteName(@Column) + ' Is Not Null) Then 0 Else 1 End'

        Delete @Temp
        Insert @Temp Execute (@sql)

        Insert  @Results
                (ColumnName)
        Select  @Column
        From    @Temp
        Where   Result = 1
    End

    Close cur        
    Deallocate cur

    Select  ColumnName
    From    @Results
    Order By ColumnName

End
```

All you need to do is supply it the database name, schema, and table name.  You can tweak this as needed.

Demo Table:

```
A           B           DummyColumn
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           NULL
1           2           NULL
1           3           NULL
2           5           NULL
2           4           NULL
3           NULL        NULL
```

Usage:

```
Execute spGetColumnsWithAllNullValues 'Sandbox', 'dbo', 'B'
```

Output:

```
ColumnName
----------------
DummyColumn
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Works perfectly. This is  what  exactly what i wanted. My up vote and tick is for you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to unpivot the values.  There are several ways.  This is a pretty easy one:

```
select name
from ngkbm_template_data_sets_ t outer apply
     (values ('txt_description_1', txt_description_1),
             ('txt_description_2', txt_description_2),
             . . .
     ) cols(name, val)
group by name
having count(val) = 0;
```

Yes, this does require listing out all the columns.  I would suggest using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and/or your favorite spreadsheet to generate the code represented by the `. . .`.

Comment: Dude i just give a table name in the whole database i have to do this operation. 
Don't stick to the table name

Comment: Please check my answer...
What you think on this

Answer (score 0):

The following script loops round all user tables in a database and prints out a line for each column in each table telling you if it contains all null values or not:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

DECLARE TableCur cursor for
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    OPEN TableCur

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCur into @SchemaName, @TableName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE ColumnCur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

        OPEN ColumnCur

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCur into @ColumnName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @COUNTER int; SELECT @COUNTER = COUNT([' + @ColumnName + ']) FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ';'
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' IF @COUNTER = 0 BEGIN SELECT ' + '''' + 'The column [' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '.'  + @ColumnName + '] has all null values' + '''' + ' END'
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ELSE BEGIN SELECT ' + '''' + 'The column ['  + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + '] has some non-null values' + '''' + ' END'

            Exec sp_executesql @SQL


            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCur into @ColumnName

        END

        CLOSE ColumnCur
        DEALLOCATE ColumnCur

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCur into @SchemaName, @TableName

    END

    CLOSE TableCur
    DEALLOCATE TableCur
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,