# How do I select only the columns with no data in them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return only columns with no data in them (all NULL values). Is there an easy and quick way to do that with a select statement?

Thanks,

Comment: WHERE Column IS NULL

Comment: If you have multiple related columns you should consider to normalize your model. Create another table which stores one value in every record and is related to the main table via foreign-key. Then you could use this query: `SELECT t1.Identifier, t2.Value, t2.Name FROM MainTable t1 INNER JOIN ValueTable t2 ON t1.Identifier=t2.ForeignKeyColumn WHERE t2.Value IS NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a large table with 324 columns, I want to get the list of columns which don't have any values at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087564/i-have-a-large-table-with-324-columns-i-want-to-get-the-list-of-columns-which-d)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Editing based on response

This will return a list of all the columns and the number of records within it. 
All you have to do is filter the output to non_null

```
declare @table_name as varchar(128) = ''; -- your table name here
declare @column_name as varchar(128);
declare @sql as nvarchar(4000);
declare @count_column int;
declare @tmp_table_result as table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    table_object_id bigint,
    column_name varchar(128),
    non_null_records int
    );
declare csr cursor for 
select name
from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name);
open csr;
fetch next from csr into @column_name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
set @sql = 'select @cnt_col = count(' + @column_name + ') from ' + @table_name;
print @sql
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@cnt_col int output', @cnt_col=@count_column OUTPUT;

insert into @tmp_table_result (table_object_id, column_name, non_null_records)
values (
    object_id(@table_name),
    @column_name,
    @count_column
    );
fetch next from csr into @column_name;
END
close csr;
deallocate csr;
select * 
from @tmp_table_result
```

Comment: This will return only the column that I specify in the query. What I really want is to return ALL columns that are all NULL.

Thanks,

Comment: Edit based on your response.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

select * from table where 1=2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).